# Adjust height of jquery chosen select box

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-chosen

I am using jquery chosen for my (single select) dropdowns with about 1000 options. By default the chosen select box shows (only) 10 options.
What I want is to show more than this 10 options eg. 20-30 options. Therefore I want to adapt the height of the select box. What I did is the following:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

This seems to work as the select box has the wanted height (600px) and shows now more than 10 options.
**But then the scrolling does not work properly anymore**: When I move the mouse towards the 10th option the scrolling effect already starts although there are about 15 more options shown under them. So the scrolling effect reacts too early. It seems that chosen still "thinks" that only 10 options are shown and scrolling effect has to start.

Thank you in advance for your helpful answers on how to get the select box with a larger height and still having the scrolling working properly!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about this issue?